# Why are LINQ calls from PowerShell much faster the second time around

Tags: c#, linq, powershell, clr

Consider the following PowerShell code:

```
PS> [int[]] $numbers = 1..10000
PS> (measure-command { [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum($numbers) }).TotalMilliseconds
28.8624
```

If I then simply repeat the same `Measure-Command` invocation it runs an order of magnitude faster:

```
PS> (measure-command { [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum($numbers) }).TotalMilliseconds
2.6828
```

Subsequent repetitions are varied but within the same range:

```
PS> (measure-command { [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum($numbers) }).TotalMilliseconds
1.504
PS> (measure-command { [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum($numbers) }).TotalMilliseconds
2.0782
PS> (measure-command { [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum($numbers) }).TotalMilliseconds
1.3351
```

What kind of overhead is there for invoking a method from the CLR? It is just time loading then caching the assembly or something else...?

Comment: there is jitter (?)

Comment: possibly Caching?

Answer (score 2):

The first time around, the System.Core dll has to be loaded. That requires a **file read** and could account for the overhead you are seeing.

[image: Procmon Trace]

Answer (score 0):

> CLR converts the MSIL as needed during execution and stores the resulting native code in memory so that it is accessible for subsequent calls in the context of that process.

I think the first time will be when converting the managed code to native code, then the its cached in memory.

check this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5532s8a(v=vs.110).aspx